# Elasticsearch indexing measurement unit with and without whitespace consistently

Tags: elasticsearch

So what I'm after is indexing measurement units consistently regardless if there's a whitespace between the number and the unit or not.

I've done this using a pattern_capture filter:

```json
GET /_analyze
{
  "char_filter": [
    {
      "pattern": "(\\d+)\\s*(cm|m|in)",
      "type": "pattern_replace",
      "replacement": "$1_$2"
    }
  ],
  "text": ["10cm", "10 cm"]
}
```

Which produces what I expect:

```json
{
  "tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "10_cm",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 4,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 0
    },
    {
      "token" : "10_cm",
      "start_offset" : 5,
      "end_offset" : 10,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 101
    }
  ]
}
```

And while this works, I'm unsure about pattern capture performance. There are Regex warnings all over the Elasticsearch documentation and I'm a little bit afraid it could impact performance too much.

Maybe there's a better way to analyze such kinds of units more consistently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right to be careful with performance and regex in Elasticsearch.
You can use a simple regex at ingestion. But it depends on your implementation.

The main risk is to introduce another or several others loops inside the loop of indexing processes.
So it's very dangerous on large text fields.
But it should not on your use case it does not change.

At first, you should flag your regex to avoid loops even if a user send a wrong data (10cm 20cm 14cm etc.... instead of only one value inside the field could be problematic) if it's possible in your use case, add ^regex$

```
GET /_analyze
{
  "char_filter": [
    {
      "pattern": "^(\\d+)\\s*(cm|m|in)$",
      "type": "pattern_replace",
      "replacement": "$1_$2"
    }
  ],
  "text": ["10cm", "10 cm", "a10cm", "10 cm3"]
}
```

Last 2 examples will be ignored.

```
{
  "tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "10_cm",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 4,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 0
    },
    {
      "token" : "10_cm",
      "start_offset" : 5,
      "end_offset" : 10,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 101
    },
    {
      "token" : "a10cm",
      "start_offset" : 11,
      "end_offset" : 16,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 202
    },
    {
      "token" : "10 cm3",
      "start_offset" : 17,
      "end_offset" : 23,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 303
    }
  ]
}
```

But the only way to really measure the influences of this change within your cluster is to test it.
You can create your own benchmark, or use [Rally](https://github.com/elastic/rally) and define a Race to test with a large volume of data.